# Finding document with regex but the input is array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find solution for findig document with array search input. Solution on next line is working great, but i need to do more complex search.

```
const searchInput = ["United States","Mexico"]  
model.find({country: { $in: searchInput },})
```

The data has "country" field in various forms and for that reason i need to use regex. For which the following solution works if only one country is searched.

```
model.find({country : {$regex : "United States"}});
```

But I need to combine the previous two solutions. Do I need to do a separate search for each element in the array, or is there a better solution?

```
Example data:

0: {country: "United States"}
1: {country: "Mexico"}
2: {country: "Canada"}
3: {country: "United States | Canada"}
```

From these documents, I want to find only those that match the search equals ["United States","Mexico"].

```
Expected results:

0: {country: "United States"}
1: {country: "Mexico"}
3: {country: "United States | Canada"}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pipes instead of array, like this:

```
model.find({
  country: {
    $regex: "United States|Mexico"
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M_hzpvtntj5).

Of course you can use an aggregation pipeline to build the string with pipes from the array, but I think it will be simpler and cleaner to do it in the code and use a simple `find`

Comment: Thanks! So my solution is pretty easy with let searchInputRegex = searchInput.join("|") and your find function!